# The labels don't update when the selected item in DropDownList changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to use the DropDownList to update the content of a label.

The first one is the Asynchronous Transfer Mode. The page doesn't refresh when a new item is selected.

The second one is the Synchronous Transfer Mode. The entire page is refreshed when a new item is selected.

However, neither of these two labels refreshed as I like when I tried to selected a new item in my DropDownList.

Could anyone help me?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ex8_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            Password：<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            Asynchronous Transfer Mode</div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1"
                    EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <p>
            Show selected item <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
        <p>
            Synchronous Transfer Mode</p>
        <p>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </p>
        <p>
            Show selected item <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ex8_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DropDownList1` is inside `UpdatePanel`, while `Label1` is outside of it. `UpdatePanel` enables rendering part of a page which is inside of it. Therefore `Label1` keeps the old value. If you place `Label1` inside `UpdatePanel`, more precise inside `ContentTemplate`, you will see the change of the label.

`UpdatePanel` renders part of the page without postback. You can see that when you select an item from `DropDownList1` there is no new *go back arrow* in your browser. The best way to check this is when you open the *.aspx* page and first select an item from `DropDownList1`. *Go back arrow* will still be disabled.

`DropDownList2` is not inside an *UpdatePanel* and it uses postback to render entire page. This is the reason why `Label1`, if it is outside `UpdatePanel`, sets its value to selected item from `DropDownList1` when you select an item from `DropDownList2`. `Label1` got the selected item from `DropDownList1`, it just waits for the postback, which is fired by `DropDownList1`.

To update `Label2` you need to add event handler `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"` to `DropDownList2`.

Answer (score 0):

When removed UdpatePanel control, the DropDownList after SelectedIndexChanged, Label is updated with selectedvalue.

The ScriptManager and UpdatePanel controls remove the requirement to refresh the whole page with each postback, which improves the user experience.

[More Information Here!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb399001(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

You can have one global UpdatePanel and then use UpdatePanels as per requirements. And then controls may not be restricted to particular UpdatePanel. It still gets refreshed.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList 
                                ID="DropDownList1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Show selected item <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </p>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```